# Is there a way to print the definition of an existing function in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp, lisp

I want to see the definition of an existing function in Emacs. Is this possible?

I've tried `C-h d function-name RET`, but it only returns the documentation string for the function, not the actual function itself.

I'm thinking something similar to bash's `type` command, which will return the whole definition of a function.

(Embarrassing backstory: I accidentally wrote over a working function in my `.emacs` file with a non-working version. The original function is still in memory! And it works! But I cannot for the *life* of me remember how I did it.)

Comment: If you've kept `.emacs` opened in a buffer, try undoing like crazy.

Answer (score 11):

If you type `C-h f function-name RET`, you'll get the function's documentation, with a link to  the function source if available.

I don't think there's an easy Lisp function you can call to retrieve the location of a function's source; the lookup is pretty intertwined with the rest of the help system. `find-lisp-object-file-name` is the main function that attempts to figure out where the source of a function is.

Unless `function-name` is a primitive (defined in Emacs's C source), you can see its code with `(symbol-function 'function-name)`, or more generally (indirect-function 'function-name). However, if the function was byte-compiled, all you'll see is its bytecode.

Comment: Thank you! `(symbol-function 'function-name)` is exactly what I was looking for! Also, it looks like if you really need the source to C functions you can get it using information from Oleg's answer.

Comment: Thanks! Also, if the function is autoloaded, you need to call it once before you can get the source code.

Answer (score 3):

`M-x find-function` returns the definition of the function near the point.

From the documentation:

> Finds the source file containing the definition of the function near
>   point (selected by `function-called-at-point') in a buffer and places
>   point before the definition. Set mark before moving, if the buffer
>   already existed.

If you want to include also functions implemented in C you have to add the following to your .emacs file:

```
(setq find-function-C-source-directory (concat (getenv "emacs_home") "/path/to/source-dir"))
```

Comment: Hmm. This is good to know, but I think it only works for built-in functions, which isn't what I was looking for.

Comment: It works for user-defined functions as well